# libvirt-python missing methods

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, libvirt

libvirt-python version 1.2.9 (latest version on pypi) is missing methods when compiled against libvirt 1.2.10 from brew.

After opening a connections, the only methods the connection object implements are close, virConnGetLastError and virConnResetLastError.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the API XML format has been changed in version 1.2.10 (/usr/local/Cellar/libvirt/1.2.10/share/libvirt/api/libvirt-api.xml when installed from brew)
Simply install the old 1.2.9 version:

```
brew edit libvirt
```

change url and sha1

```
url "http://libvirt.org/sources/libvirt-1.2.9.tar.gz"
sha256 "95931a5a52f451b9ab73d6a5ae11a5740e1ba69a66520c2a0cffc6068a7e8fc4"
```

uninstall libvirt and reinstall from source

```
brew uninstall libvirt
brew install --build-from-source libvirt
```